# Wordpress for Google App Engine has NO "Publish" Button

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I want to use wordpress as CMS for my new project with Google App Engine. I followed this guide: http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/ and now I'm testing it **locally**. However I noticed that there is no publish sidebar with the "publish" button when I add new page or edit the sample page.

[image]

There is not even a "save draft" button.

I think I followed the steps carefully and there is no error on browser console. I believe it should be on the right side as seen on the **dashboard on wordpress.com** when you add a new page:

[image]

I found a workaround tho on how to publish. Whenever I typed in the textbox my work is then being auto save as a draft. What I do is go to the "All Pages" listing and do a "Quick Edit" on the page, I can then change the status from "Draft" to "Published" to publish that page. [image]

But it would be very convenient if I can directly publish it once I finished, without going to the page listing and doing a quick edit. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: look in the admin console logs of your application and see if any URLs are returning a 404 - perhaps your app.yaml is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the same issue as [Google Appengine 1.9.3/4 and WordPress 3.9 Admin User not Fully Functional on Localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678365/google-appengine-1-9-3-4-and-wordpress-3-9-admin-user-not-fully-functional-on-lo)

It only affects Windows and should be fixed in the 1.9.7 release of SDK.