# Google Appengine 1.9.3/4 and WordPress 3.9 Admin User not Fully Functional on Localhost

Tags: php, python, wordpress, google-app-engine

I am getting several errors at different moments when using my local copy of wordpress on appengine.

It happens when clicking on "Posts", which shows error "**Invalid post type**", or when trying to create a new post, there is no save box/button.

It also happens when trying to change options in one of my themes in other places with plugins.

I get a lot of "**You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page**."

For the most part, the back-end is functional, the front-end is fully functional.

I am using appengine 1.9.3 and wordpress 3.9, python 2.7.6.

I have uninstalled 1.9.3 and updated to 1.9.4, I have also accepted Wordpress' request to install 3.9.1, the problem persists.

I have installed the 1.9.3, 3.9, 2.7.6 configuration on a different machine where app engine was never installed before and the same problem occurs.

I had appengine 1.9.0 and 1.9.3 working with WordPress 3.8.1.

The problem started a few days ago after a number of upgrades (from 1.9.3 to 1.9.4, and into wordpress 3.9.1).

Could this be related to additional layer on WPDB added in 3.9? http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/07/mysql-in-wordpress-3-9/

Questions:

1. Anybody else experiencing similar behavior?
2. Will this propagate to google cloud if I update the version with launcher?
3. How do I solve this on my local copy?

Please, help!

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this issue on OS X.  What OS are you using?  Also, I wonder if it could be an interaction with one of your plugins.  Could you try a trimmed-down install via: http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/ or: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks for replying, @Amy_U. I am running all this on Windows 7.

I suspected a stubborn plugin, or a mix of them, could be the culprit until I  installed the entire set on a separate machine I never used to run Wordpress (no plugins other than the default appengine ones ever existed there). Yet, the problem still occurs.

That separate machine has a SQL Server OS, so still Windows.

I used the fresh trimmed-down from github in the Win7 and SQL Server machines.

Comment: We'll look into this further and post an update here.

Comment: I just gave it another try and downloaded the latest version from the git repository per your suggestion, @Amy_U. The errors persists.

Comment: @Amy_U: I have just deployed the latest from my hard-drive by using the app launcher and the code in the cloud seems to be working fine. I have no strange error messages in the cloud, all plugins work just fine. It seems the problem is only in the local machine.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. I'm able to reproduce the error on Windows. Working on a fix.

Comment: Is there anything else I can provide you with to help troubleshoot. Something in my OS, list of applications, versions, etc.? Please, let me know, I am starting to believe this is something small that we are not thinking about and simply escaping our attempts to solve it. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I too get this issue on the local environment. I haven't tried deploying to the cloud yet.

Answer (score 1):

This has something to do with the fact that Windows uses backslashes ("\") instead of forward slashes ("/") for its directory structure.

Try adding this in your wp-config.php just before require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php'); for a quick fix.

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = str_replace('\', '/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Comment: This issue should be fixed in the next release of SDK.